# Retrieving few parameters of a json array object and displaying them in another function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a json response object in the cellForRow method which looks like this :

```
{
geofenceType="a";
resourceType="b";
requestType="c";
monitoringType="d";
},
{
geofenceType="a1";
resourcetype="b1";
requestType="c1";
monitoringType="d1";
}, ...and so on for different users.
```

I have a button infront of every user so that only the details of the user selected get passed.So I am doing it by tags something like:

```
CellForRow:
{
myAray=json; (now this has the values of all users and myArray is declared in the .h file)
UIButton *b=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,0,40,40)];
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventsTouchUpInside];
b.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell addSubview:b];
}
-(void) buttonPressed:(id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent*) event{
UIButton *mybtn=(UIButton*) sender;
NSMutableArray * localArray;
localArray=[myArray objectAtIndex:mybtn.tag];
}
```

Problem:Throws an exception and localArray does not get printed.

Answer (score 0):

do you see that these are the different ivars:

```
myAray=json;

[myArray objectAtIndex:mybtn.tag];
```

Comment: please provide the solution. I have spent a lot of time on this. :|

Comment: change the name of ivar either to myAray or myArray (that should be better:))

Comment: of course AppDelegate may also be right - are you sure that you actually have an array there?? Log it out
NSLog(@"class is:%@", [[myArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag] class])

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17242/discussion-between-hakunamatata-and-stas)

Answer (score 0):

myArray probably consist of dataType "Dictionary"

try this instead of NSMutableArray *localArray;

```
NSDictionary *dict =[myArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

Comment: json is of type NSArray. and so is myArray.

Comment: true,but it contains {..} curly brackets,which represents dictionary..so the face is that myArray is an array of dictionaries.does the above code work

Comment: can u give me the output of myArray and firstly why are you loading data of myArray in 'cellForRow' , it is advisable to load it in viewDidLoad or other function

Comment: gosh, log it out! i've already provided a log to copy-paste just do it

Comment: I pasted that in the question.

Comment: I can show you the commands I wrote before myArray=json.
JSONDecoder *decoder=[[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptions];
NSArray *json=[decoder objectWithData:myData]; (myData contains that data)

Comment: I have done the exact same thing in another view controller. the difference was just that there the array was not of dictionary type..its working fine there.

Comment: try populating myArray in viewDidLoad instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath..i suppose ur 'cellForRow' gets called every time for number of cells in your tableview

Comment: Funny story...instead of buttonPressed...I was using  ButtonPressed :D
its working now..thanks a tonne :)

Comment: To be honest you must accept my answer because this is your second question I'm trying to answer, the first was correct but you accepted App's answer so now accept mine